# How to declare an array variable to be global in module scope

Tags: perl, module, scope

I have some code I decided to pull into a module in perl.  I admit that I am doing a bit of monkey-see monkey-do stuff following documentation I've found online.

There is only one pubicly visible subroutine, which sets 2 variables * would like to use in other subroutines in the module, without passing them explicitly as parameters --  $fname, and @lines.  Looking online I came up with the "our" keyword, but when I try to declare them at global level (see code snippet below), I get the following error:

```
mig_tools.pm did not return a true value at
```

I have worked around the issue by declaring "our $fname" and "our @lines" in every subroutine they are used, but I would prefer to declare them once at global scope.  Is that possible?

Here's what I take to be the relevant part of the code.

```
package mig_tools;
require Exporter;

use strict;
use warnings;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw( ensure_included);

our $fname;
our @lines;

// definitions of already_has_include find_include_insert_point and ensure_included.
```

Answer (score 2):

All-lowercase variables are reserved for local identifiers and pragma names. Your module should be in `MigTools.pm` and you should use it with `use MigTools`

The `did not return a true value` error is just because your module file didn't return a *true* value when it was executed. It is usual to add a line containing just `1;` to the end of all modules

Your `MigTools.pm` should look like this. It is best to use the `import` directly from `Exporter` instead of subclassing it, and `our` doesn't help you to create a global variable, but I am a little worried about why you are structuring your module this way

```
package MigTools;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw/ import /;

our @EXPORT = qw/ ensure_included /;

my ($fname, @lines)

sub ensure_included {

}

sub already_has_include {

}

sub find_include_insert_point {

}

sub ensure_included {

}

1;
```